# How to resize the UITableView Cell height to fit the UITextView content in it?

Tags: uitableview, uitextview

I have tried the following in heightForRowAtIndexPath,

CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300.0, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
return size.height + 50;

This seems fine when the length of the text is not too long, but when I put some articles in it, then there is a great error of the heigh.

How can I solve this? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to put the text in a `UILabel` and call `sizeToFit` on the label. If you use an actual prototype instance of your cell, you can avoid hard-coding the font metrics in your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method.

There is a working example in the [TLIndexPathTools library](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools), which has a `TLDynamicSizeView` protocol to simplify dynamic height cells. Take a look at the [Dynamic Height](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Dynamic%20Height/Dynamic%20Height/DynamicHeightTableViewController.m) example project.

Comment: sizeToFit doesn't seem to work on iOS7. It would be great if you can provide code of your DynamicCell in the answer.

Comment: @ruslan The Dynamic Height sample project I linked to in the answer works in iOS7. I got it to work using both `sizeToFit` and `intrinsicContentSize`, though at the time I didn't fully understand why it worked (and I haven't revisited it). Here is a direct link to that code: https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Dynamic%20Height/Dynamic%20Height/DynamicHeightCell.m